# What is the format of connection string that should be used while using ERWin tool for generating ERD for an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle10g, erwin

I have been trying to generate an ERD for some oracle database. While I am doing this via 'Actions'->'Reverse Engineering' option, I get a section that asks me for a connection string. But I am unsure of the format about how we can specify the database and its details. 
Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks 
Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Erwin 7.3.8 to connect on a Oracle 11g schema.  The connection works from me when I use the *oracle tnsnames* string format:

For example:

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **database-server**)(PORT = **database-server-port**))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = **service-name-if-exists**)))
```

Copy as a one line command and paste in the **Connection String** field.

Cheers!