# I need the connection string for CA ERWIN Data modeler

Tags: ca, erwin

What is the connection string value format for CA Erwin DA modeler to Oracle? I know you can't simply type in the database name.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506283/what-is-the-format-of-connection-string-that-should-be-used-while-using-erwin-to

Comment: now i cant click on database connections for some odd reason???

Comment: nevermind, i had it set to logical model instead of physical model

Comment: It now is giving me the "invalid username/password" logon denied error

Comment: that string suggestion doesn't work. okay?