# what is the connection string for forward engineering into oracle databases with CA erwin

Tags: oracle, ca, erwin

I tried using the green checkmarked solution in [What is the format of connection string that should be used while using ERWin tool for generating ERD for an Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506283/what-is-the-format-of-connection-string-that-should-be-used-while-using-erwin-to)  typing it out as I found it in the tns.ora docs. Maybe I am doing something wrong but I don't know what it is.
Can someone please tell me the exact format for inserting a connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the format of connection string that should be used while using ERWin tool for generating ERD for an Oracle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506283/what-is-the-format-of-connection-string-that-should-be-used-while-using-erwin-to)

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: Raul, i literally copy and pasted the link because I wanted to let everyone know that either its not working or i'm doing something wrong but im not sure exactly what it is. Please give me an answer.

Comment: In my opinion, in such case, either you should put a comment in original question, OR, if asking a new question - provide necessary details / step / issue etc here itself.